# How to Draw a TextView into a Canvas then change the text later

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a canvas and I write a textView to the canvas. The problem is: later I need to change the text in the TextView but I don't know how to update the canvas (erase the previous text and insert the new one). I can't clear using setColor(Color.Black) because I have an image in the Canvas.

Code:

```
       LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);

        TextView textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        textView.setText("Hello world");
        layout.addView(textView);

        layout.measure(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        layout.layout(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        layout.draw(mCanvas);

        textView.setText("ABC");

        textView.invalidate();
        textView.postInvalidate();
        layout.invalidate();
        layout.postInvalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setter like this in a custom view.

```
public synchronized void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
    postInvalidate();
}
```

If you didn't use a custom view, you should call `view.postInvalidate()`

Comment: Could you give me more information? Where should I use this setters?Should I create a class with a textview and a text?

Comment: Did you use this in a custom view?

Comment: No I didn't, but if is the only way I could implement it

Comment: you should call `view.postInvalidate()` after set text

Comment: sorry but I still don't know what should I do.. I tried calling this method but nothing happens, the first text is still on the image and I don't know where is the new one

Comment: Did you set new text?

Comment: Don't you use `canvas.drawText`, why change to `textview.setText()`